# single sign on java and active directories

Tags: authentication, active-directory, weblogic, single-sign-on

We have number of intranets sites, hosted in web logic server, each have its own authentication framework. Now we have a new requests to implement the single sign on. There is another  team who are communicating with active directories [pass the domain name and username like phillip_r and it will return the primary email etc], how do I utilize , I read few article about CAS, Kerbos etc and now I more confused do I need to implement them in my case or not, please help me on this, as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebLogic is not 'kerberized' so you can not actual use Kerberos. However you can use WebLogic's SPNEGO handler to provide 'auto-login' from user perspective this is like 'single-sign on' but actually it's only 'auto-login'. The Kerberos token provided via SPNEGO typically has 'userpricipalname@REALM' ... that can be email address, but most of the time it's not email. It will not return arbitrary attributes from AD... you have to do this own your own (e.g. via LDAP).

However Kerberos via HTTP (SPNEGO) only works for enterprise clients, which can directly communicate with the Key Distribution Center (AD KDC).

CAS or OpenAM (http://openam.forgerock.org) are web-based, java-based single sign on systems which offer different means for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all apps are on Weblogic and all users are in AD domain, you can use Kerberos SSO for all of them with no problem and don't need CAS. Set it up using instructions from Oracle.